# Removing ordinals in a string with Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm working on a website that uses an events list widget to pull in current events. By default, the dates are displayed with ordinals (st / rd / th / nd after the numbers, i.e. '18th May'). I want to remove these from every event using Javascript / jQuery so that it reads '18 May' instead.

Initially I had four separate scripts to remove each of these, but I was sure there must be an easier way - lo and behold, I discovered RegEx.

Having searched this site already, I came across this live demo:

https://regex101.com/r/pN4oG0/1

This does exactly what I'd like, so I combined this with some other bits (addition of /g after the expression so that it affects all instances of .msl_event_item) to try and fix the issue.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var str = $(".msl_event_time").html();
    str.replace(/(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)/g, "$1");
    console.log(str);
});
```

I really thought that this would work and I can't see any reason why it wouldn't, but as I literally only just discovered RegEx today and scripting is not my strongest skill, I'm struggling to make any further progress - the console just reads "18th May - 8th June" no matter what I do.

The live site is here so that you can see the full markup:

https://www.su.rhul.ac.uk/thepackhorse/events/

And a simplified version of the markup below:

**EDIT: Definitely accidentally put the wrong class in here initially (msl_event_item instead of msl_event_time) so I've got the responses working now!**

```
<div class="event_item">
    <dd class="msl_event_time">
    18th May - 8th June
    </dd>
</div>

<div class="event_item">
    <dd class="msl_event_time">
    7th June
    </dd>
</div>
```

Essentially, I need a code that will remove ordinals for every event item. **I cannot change the HTML markup** - it's generated by the content management system's widget. It doesn't matter to me how the code works, as long as it uses Javascript or jQuery.

Any ideas?

Comment: You simply miss `str = ` in front of `str.replace(/(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)/g, "$1");`

Comment: @baao, it's very vaguely similar and IMO unlikely to help the OP answer their question.

Comment: @George Did you look at my answer to the duplicate? Can you explain what exactly would be different from that answer to this one? (other than replacing padStart with replace)

Comment: How can this be duplicate ?

Comment: Look at the [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ERKrGw?editors=1111) were you will see your very tiny error. ;)

Comment: @baao Yes. Even if the OP were to assign their replacement to `str`, they wouldn't get the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't doing anything with the value after performing your replacement. If you were to *re-assign* your string when doing the replacement (`str = str.replace(/(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)/g, "$1")`), you'd see the modified string in the console. Having said that...

jQuery gives us the ability to pass a callback function to `.html()`. When you do that, the returning result of that callback function will become the new HTML for each element in the collection:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.msl_event_item').html(function(_, v){

        // In this callback, 'v' is the HTML that
        // currently resides inside our element

        return v.replace(/(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)/g, "$1");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event_item">
    <dd class="msl_event_item">
    18th May - 8th June
    </dd>
</div>

<div class="event_item">
    <dd class="msl_event_item">
    7th June
    </dd>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It **is** working...

But you do not assign" the new `str` value befor the `console.log()`!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var str = $(".msl_event_time").html();
    str = str.replace(/(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)/g, "$1");
    console.log(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="msl_event_time">18th May - 8th June</div>
```

Comment: To downvoter... Did you run the snippet? The expected result is there.

Comment: Sorry, missclicked before

Answer (score 0):

You have to reassign the string, then set the elements content to the updated value. Below is a verbose version, [@George's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50702336/3993662) is better here, but I wanted to explain the real error. Strings are immutable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    const el = $(".msl_event_item");
    el.each(function() {
      let str = $(this).html();
      // you need to reassign to str !
      str = str.replace(/(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)/g, "$1");
      $(this).html(str)
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event_item">
    <dd class="msl_event_item">
    18th May - 8th June
    </dd>
</div>

<div class="event_item">
    <dd class="msl_event_item">
    7th June
    </dd>
</div>
```

---

I'm sure you knew the trick how to set the elements html content. The error in your code was not to reassign the returned value from `str.replace()` to `str`